# Можно ли измерить производительность ПК с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

При разработке корпоративного веб-интерфейса, иногда приходиться отказываться от визуализации, как излишней графической нагрузки, т.к. часть парка ПК морально устарела.
В связи  этим есть идея - при инициализации соединения выполнять определенный benchmark, и по факту ответа от клиента запускать облегченную или обычную версию сайта (скорее всего такое будет и для нестабильных удаленных соединений). 

Вопрос в том, существует ли алгоритм для объективной оценки производительности ПК?

Comment: Вам не нужна производительность ПК. Вам нужна производительность JS на этом пк. Для таких целей подойдет любой тест производительности Javascript. Так же рекомендую посмотреть в сторону WebGL для графики и asm.js для вычислений если у вас есть какие либо тяжеловесные задачи. Хотя если говорить честно, даже в корпоративном сайте мне сложно представить, что бы у браузера были проблемы с визуальной частью сайта.

Comment: проблемы не с отображением, а с активностью поедания оперативки каждой открытой вкладкой

Comment: В таком случае вам стоило бы открыть вопрос именно о проблеме с памятью. Возможно у вас есть утечки памяти. Если же вы просто работаете с большим количеством данных используйте аjax и храните в памяти только нужные на данный момент данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучив профильные для этого вопроса плагины, а именно `benchmark.js` и `jslitmus.js` могу подтвердить их точность замеров. Конкретно в моем примере, работать с ними оказалось не совсем удобно, да и прецизионная точность для меня была не важна.
В итоге, решил сделать замер времени, необходимого для многократного расчета факториала числа. Количество итераций и n-факториала подбирал до тех пор, пока разброс значений при многократных запусках отличался не более чем на 5%. 
 
 Код получился небольшой, и, на сегодняшний день, он благополучно собрал статистику со всех браузеров. Статистика уже хранится в профиле каждого клиента и будет запрашиваться от клиента один раз в месяц. 
 Приемлемые показатели производительности (а это менее чем 1000 мс) имеются только у 40 из 60 клиентов, и для них будет применяться дефолтный интерфейс. Для остальных "счастливчиков", т.е. обладателей железа старше 15 лет, содержание страниц будет урезаться для приемлемой скорости работы.

JS

```
function factor(depth) { 
  var f=1; 
  for(var i=1; i<depth; i++) { 
    f=f*i; 
  }
  return f; 
} 

function load(amount,depth) {
    var t0 = performance.now();
  for(var n=1; n<amount; n++) { 
        var result = factor(depth);
  }
    var t1 = performance.now();
    var duration = (t1 - t0).toFixed(0);
  return duration;
}

var duration = load(10000,20000); // Это значение вернется на сервер и запишется в профиль пользователя

document.write(duration+"ms");
```

[Запустить пример расчета](https://jsfiddle.net/Poul_WWJD/b1vvspsq/1/)